# Creating cookies in cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies, cucumber

I am trying to begin testing using cucumber however, when I write this:

```
Given /^I am not authenticated$/ do
  cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = nil
end
```

I get this error

```
undefined method `permanent' for #<Rack::Test::CookieJar:0x00000100f8f8f8> (NoMethodError)
      ./features/step_definitions/sign_up_steps.rb:2:in `/^I am not authenticated$/'
      features/sign_up.feature:8:in `And I am not authenticated'
```

Comment: CookieJar doesn't have a permanent method?